# RestTemplate - 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE Error

Tags: spring-boot, rest, resttemplate, http-status-code-415

I want to call a REST service from my application. I'm not passing any request to this call. But I can't figure out from where it comes from?

```java
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

        map.add("username", bonitaUsername);
        map.add("password", bonitaPassword);
        map.add("redirect", "false");

        HttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        HttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverternew = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
        converters.add(stringHttpMessageConverternew);
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        ResponseEntity<?> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);

        List<String> cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");

        String cookieString = "";

        for (String cookie : cookies) {
            System.out.println();
            cookieString += cookie.split(";")[0] + "; ";
        }

        return cookieString;
```

Comment: your sending form data and it seems the backend can't handle content type MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens due to the mismatch of content types which passing to REST template. Please make sure to send the correct content type. Some times we are receiving JSON request but we need to send as another format.